# Using regex to isolate the file name and extension from an S3 presigned URL

Tags: regex

I am trying to isolate the filename from an S3 presigned URL.

The presigned URL looks like this

```
"https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/link.link2.website.com/link-file/item-file/item_id%3D168cc901-41fe-4994-a5dd-fbcc7bf1d649/date%3D2021-10-01/item-file-test%20%282%29.xlsx?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATIQ7FVSIUGCQZL7N%2F20220106%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220106T072037Z&X-Amz-Expires=14400&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJHMEUCIQD8zcE7Dk0NBD2F%2Fr9hyTzZop0%2BeJ%2BnQAthpBO3OaGR7AIgI03YGJOTcNzQ79JjZYQvI4HD4A8hKNC5Edq%2FSXiMZTEqugIIoP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARADGgwyMjQ0NNpe7sy2dtEb%2BtoeBydBYt%2B5PfH6o1ISCeGe6WfuUaFQZEM0Yl2AUGhGb06S8dTDEsNqOBjqaAadtJx31fGUhIHkaE21M%2BJffVKmz9XXYeGx2MmpllUzCUbD7vEBM%2BKxJs5XQ%2BiZs5sslLFdfjMaWbrFYgUmMLX6fz4HXABR6zFIBH%2FiIvtijgX4dkXHUWssRHZD96Qo2ATHWVhM%2FxW4ut1LkLJt1c9U44L9eofZ2Zwp5vLyEIem6c2Nmwx0eo4uc2G%2Bk5CTMF8WfWYRMYPHpksM%3D&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=&X-Amz-Signature=2395e814f4d8daa5ae86f9b40b76c16f042757008c595fc1c"
```

I just want to take out the `item-file-test.xlsx` part. How can I go about in doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: The decoded filename looks like `item-file-test (2).xlsx`, doesn't it?

Comment: You're correct! My bad, I didn't catch that. Would that make it impossible to regex, if so?

Comment: It will require two steps: 1) extract the encoded filename with regex. 2) percent-decode the filename. It wil be a help to answer if you can specify the available programming language(s), such as python or perl.

Comment: Was hoping to do this on the front end (Vue.js) by displaying the file name. The S3 presigned URL is called by an API call using Typescript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically you need to search for the last string not containing a `slash`. You might want to use `String.replace` or `String.match` for this. Here an example using `String.replace`:

```js
const input_uri = "https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/link.link2.website.com/link-file/item-file/item_id%3D168cc901-41fe-4994-a5dd-fbcc7bf1d649/date%3D2021-10-01/item-file-test%20%282%29.xlsx?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATIQ7FVSIUGCQZL7N%2F20220106%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220106T072037Z&X-Amz-Expires=14400&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJHMEUCIQD8zcE7Dk0NBD2F%2Fr9hyTzZop0%2BeJ%2BnQAthpBO3OaGR7AIgI03YGJOTcNzQ79JjZYQvI4HD4A8hKNC5Edq%2FSXiMZTEqugIIoP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARADGgwyMjQ0NNpe7sy2dtEb%2BtoeBydBYt%2B5PfH6o1ISCeGe6WfuUaFQZEM0Yl2AUGhGb06S8dTDEsNqOBjqaAadtJx31fGUhIHkaE21M%2BJffVKmz9XXYeGx2MmpllUzCUbD7vEBM%2BKxJs5XQ%2BiZs5sslLFdfjMaWbrFYgUmMLX6fz4HXABR6zFIBH%2FiIvtijgX4dkXHUWssRHZD96Qo2ATHWVhM%2FxW4ut1LkLJt1c9U44L9eofZ2Zwp5vLyEIem6c2Nmwx0eo4uc2G%2Bk5CTMF8WfWYRMYPHpksM%3D&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=&X-Amz-Signature=2395e814f4d8daa5ae86f9b40b76c16f042757008c595fc1c";

const encoded_filename = input_uri.replace(/^.*\/([^/]+?)\?.*$/, '$1');
const plain_filename= decodeURI(encoded_filename);

console.log(plain_filename);
```

The Regex `/^.*\/([^/]+?)\?.*$/` matches:

- `^.*` anything (`.*`) from the start of the string (`^`)
- `\/` matches the slash character
- `([^/]+?)` creates a non-greedy (as short as possible) capture containing anything but a slash character
- `\?` matches a question mark
- `.*$` matches anything up to the end of the string

It basically replaces the URI with the first (any only) capture group of the regex (`'$1'`). After that you need to decode that URI part using `decodeURI`.

PS: Please always add the language in use as tag to your questions.